# Python Nginx Restart and Build

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I’m building a web api with Flask. I got error when I use “sudo systemctl restart nginx” for ngnix restart after server installations, wsgi installations

```
$ sudo systemctl status nginx.servic



nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-12-06 09:36:31 UTC; 23h ago
Docs: man:nginx(8)
Process: 3210037 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 06 09:36:31 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server…

Dec 06 09:36:31 nginx[3210037]: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive “brotli” in /etc/nginx/conf.d/brotli.conf:1

Dec 06 09:36:31 nginx[3210037]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Dec 06 09:36:31 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Dec 06 09:36:31 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result ‘exit-code’.

Dec 06 09:36:31 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

How can I solve this?
I checked sites-enabled and sites-available?

Comment: It says it right there - your nginx config validation failed so it can't start. looks like you are trying to use brotli that you don't have. You should either install it or remove it from config.

Comment: thanks your ans but I m sorry. What is brotli?

Comment: You can easily google that, but here's a link: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/dynamic-modules/brotli/